# orderByChild with startAt and endAt is not working for combined field

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to query with two where condition. I came to know it's not possible directly in firebase. So, I using the following method. Storing two properties as one field and querying on that field. But I'm not getting the correct result. I'm getting non-matching records as well, why?

```
await firebase
              .child(child)
              .orderByChild('t_p')
              .startAt(startAt + pId, 't_p')
              .endAt((timestamp - 1) + pId, 't_p')
              .limitToLast(15)
```

I tried the following

```
 await firebase
                  .child(child)
                  .orderByChild('t_p')
                  .startAt(startAt + pId)
                  .endAt((timestamp - 1) + pId)
                  .limitToLast(15)
```

What's the difference between these two? What is second option param in startat and endat?

My data is like this

```
{
   t_p: "145343423423_afihad223dadd"
},
{
   t_p: "1453434133323_afihad223dadd"
},
{
   t_p: "145223423423_kkkkaaass"
},
{
   t_p: "145223423450_kkkkaaass"
}
```

if I query for

```
.child(child)
              .orderByChild('t_p')
              .startAt("145223423423_kkkkaaass", 't_p')
              .endAt("145223423450_kkkkaaass", 't_p')
              .limitToLast(15)
```

I'm getting other records as well. Why?

Comment: By *other records*, do you mean `t_p: "145343423423_afihad223dadd"`?

Comment: @AL. Yes, that's correct

Comment: Don't use the second argument to `.startAt(startAt + pId, 't_p')`. It's commonly misunderstood and won't help. Aside from that can you reproduce the problem in a jsbin, so that I can have a look (and won't have to speculate on the values of `startAt`, `pId` and `timestamp`)?

Answer (score 1):

It's because it's ordered lexographically and 145343423423 is between 145223423423 and 145223423450.

Perhaps you should be storing your t_p as p_t? That way you would instead have this:

```
{
   p_t: "afihad223dadd_145343423423"
},
{
   p_t: "afihad223dadd_1453434133323"
},
{
   p_t: "kkkkaaass_145223423423"
},
{
   p_t: "kkkkaaass_145223423450"
}

.child(child)
    .orderByChild('p_t')
    .startAt("kkkkaaass_14522342342")
    .endAt("kkkkaaass_145223423450")
    .limitToLast(15)
```

You should try to store the data in the manner you're going to access it.